# I want to make scroll images onclick of button using android

Tags: android

I have added multiple images in res >> drawable folder I want to make gallery of that photos and I have added left & right arrow images.After clicking on right arrow next image should display and left arrow previous image should display.In thia way I want to scroll that images using android.Please help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/05/gallery-view-android-developer-tutorial.html